# How to use API QR Monkey with post or get method on Python

Tags: python, api, debugging, post, get

I'm trying to use the free api https://www.qrcode-monkey.com and I can't find anywhere a valid example for python, I think I followed thru the documentation. I'm doing some trial and on **POST** I continue getting method errors and on **GET** I get a lot of 400 errors...

Here is the code with both, anyone knows what I'm doing wrong? Thank you!

```
import requests
from urllib.parse import quote, urlencode


class QrManager:
    def __init__(self):
        self.url = "https://qrcode-monkey.com/"

    def get_data_post(self):
        url = self.url + "qr/custom"
        payload = {
            "data": "https://www.google.com",
            "config": {
                "body": "circle",
            },
            "size": 300,
            "download": False,
            "file": "png"
            }
        req = requests.post(url, json=payload)
        return req

    def get_data_get(self):
        template_url = self.url + "qr/custom/?{}"
        params = {
            "data": "https://www.google.com",
            "config": {
                "body": "circle",
            },
            "size": 300,
            "download": False,
            "file": "png"
        }
        url = template_url.format(urlencode(params, safe="()", quote_via=quote))
        req = requests.get(url)
        return req

qrm = QrManager()

# response = dm.get_data_post()
response = qrm.get_data_get()

print(response.status_code)
print(response.url)
print(response.text)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They didn't show it in documentation but it needs different URL - with `api.` instead of `www.`

```
https://api.qrcode-monkey.com/qr/custom
```

I used `DevTools` in Firefox/Chrome (tab:`Network`) to see url used when page generates QR.

---

There is other problem.

`POST` gives `QR` with `circles` but `GET` gives with normal `squares`.

`GET` needs to convert `config` to `json` to get `circles`

```
"config": json.dumps({"body": "circle"})
```

(but it doesn't need `urlencode`)

---

Full code.

```
import requests
#from urllib.parse import quote, urlencode
import json

class QrManager:
    def __init__(self):
        self.url = "https://api.qrcode-monkey.com/qr/custom"

    def get_data_post(self):
        # it converts `config` to `json` automatically (because it sends all `payload` as `json`)  

        payload = {
            "data": "https://blog.furas.pl",
            "config": {
                "body": "circle",
            },
            "size": 300,
            "download": False,
            "file": "png"
            }
        
        response = requests.post(self.url, json=payload)

        return response

    def get_data_get(self):
        # it needs to convert `config` to `json` manually

        payload = {
            "data": "https://blog.furas.pl",
            "config": json.dumps({
                "body": "circle"
            }),
            "size": 300,
            "download": False,
            "file": "png"
        }
        
        #payload = urlencode(payload, safe="()", quote_via=quote)
       
        response = requests.get(self.url, params=payload)

        return response

# --- main ---

qrm = QrManager()

print('\n--- GET ---\n')

response = qrm.get_data_get()
print('status:', response.status_code)
print('url:', response.url)
print(response.text[:100])

with open('QR_GET.png', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(response.content)
    
print('\n--- POST ---\n')

response = qrm.get_data_post()
print('status:', response.status_code)
print('url:', response.url)
print(response.text[:100])

with open('QR_POST.png', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(response.content)
```

Result:

```
--- GET ---

status: 200
url: https://api.qrcode-monkey.com/qr/custom?data=https%3A%2F%2Fblog.furas.pl&config=%7B%22body%22%3A+%22circle%22%7D&size=300&download=False&file=png
�PNG

IHDR\\t�{bKGD��������IDATx��ON[��š�6#�P��hŮ#H� ��[��M��T=3@J


--- POST ---

status: 200
url: https://api.qrcode-monkey.com/qr/custom
�PNG

IHDR\\t�{bKGD��������IDATx��ON[��š�6#�P��hŮ#H� ��[��M��T=3@J
```